# Actionscript 3 unescape character range

Tags: flash, actionscript, escaping, urlencode

I am developing mobile app in Flash Builder 4.6 (Flex SDK 4.6.0) as Flex Mobile Project.

I noticed this, when unescape method replaced some encoded characters as empty space.

```
trace(unescape("%8A %9F")); // traces NOTHING
```

As much as I tested, all characters within %80 - %9F are replaced with nothing. Rest of the  characters seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

After referencing this chart: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

It seems that those characters are not a standard set and flash doesn't support all of them directly.

But try this and see if you get what you're looking for:

http://snipplr.com/view/46566/as3-encode-and-decode-html-entity-names-full-set/

Comment: The class you provided is unfortunately only for HTML entity conversion ( &####; ) but I need to URL decode my texts (%##).

Comment: But like that file, if you have a way to map the chars to HTML text you should be able to see them in a TextField with HTMLText.  It's not perfect, but it gives you what you want since Flash doesn't support all the values in the trace.

Comment: You mean I should make my own function, which would decode rest of characters?

Comment: Yes - you could create a class that maps the chars.

Comment: Made a quick class for decoding missing occurrences from unescape method. Maybe someone might need it one day: http://codetidy.com/4177/

Comment: Nice - filing this away, thanks.  So did this answer your question?